# After Production mode and JS minification, 404 error for all JS files

Tags: magento2, 404, production-mode, minified-js

I have enabled JS minification and Merging while in developer mode.
Then i enabled production mode.

Cleared cache and ran below commands:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

but still i get 404 error for all JS files in console.

Magento still tries to look for Non-minified version of JS files!

**Note:** In developer mode everything works fine!